# Defining multiple mapped types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

Say I have the following typescript code:

```js
type fruit = "apple" | "banana" | "pear"
type color = "red" | "yellow" | "green"
```

And I want to create a type that has a numeric property for each fruit and a boolean property for each color, something like

```js
type FruitsAndColors = {
  [key in fruit]: number;
  [key in color]: boolean
}
```

Unfortunately, this errors with the message "A mapped type may not declare properties or methods", yet it compiles fine. What's actually happening here?

I can get around this with something like

```
type FruitsAndColors = {
  [key in fruit]: number;
} & {
  [key in color]: boolean
}
```

But I'd like to know what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not "vscode's typescript extension," it's *TypeScript*. It doesn't let you do two mappings in a single `type` construct. It's just the syntax of the construct doesn't allow it.

Instead, you do what you showed:

```typescript
type FruitsAndColors = {
    [key in fruit]: number;
} & {
    [key in color]: boolean
};
```

Note, though, that that type **requires all six properties** to be present in the object. Maybe that's what you want, but if not, add `?` after the mapped keys (or wrap the entire thing in `Partial<>`):

```typescript
type FruitsAndColors = {
    [key in fruit]?: number;
} & {
    [key in color]?: boolean
};
// Or
type FruitsAndColors = Partial<{
    [key in fruit]: number;
} & {
    [key in color]: boolean
}>;
```

[Playground for the above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=13&pln=32&pc=29#code/C4TwDgpgBAZgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8sAjbAO2u2LM0mzkwG4AoUSKAYwHt8fOOixwIAE3pYQEfIIDuUzAHMxEKm3adw0AGKIUAZwCCVcQGEBQwwEYRAb3ZRnUANoBrCCChIqsA8AAugBcUFQIALbkEHAcAL5QAGRQji5unt6+vFZwIVDkfAIQ1OxxHFx6ASZmloJwhgBMIgAKzMBI2PgAPKkuHl4+fvDIQaHhUTHxSSlOfRmD2XV5BUUlcQB8HOwA9NtQuthI+Ib5EDzYCIbQfDBQEUiGhr7KUGBwfJBw7RCG7PxUhlQMGwPBsoX0I2qFhytgcs2cuAIEFCNgANPCoGJxKFgIgIOiylpdlAAOpCdwnaLnS7QYAACy8AHIxFBOvgoPSYhA-nwAUCQQ1wVVTNC6rCML0EXhCCj0WlKDQaKEGnKXEw4KEAMyq5xYnF4nVQGRyPjyULA474jGqCDqfUIK2EnZ7MlwCmnalXDkM17vT7fE7Ma5gdq8zo8vmwEGaoWQkW1axNCUYxEyqBojF6jkG0ocIA)

Comment: @Emanresua - No worries. Actually, I've referred to "index signatures" above, but they aren't, are they? So my bad. :-D I've fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use conditional types:

```
type FruitsAndColors = Partial<{
  [Key in (Fruit | Color)]: Key extends Fruit ? number : Key extends Color ? boolean : never;
}>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8sAjbAO2u2LM0mzkwChRIoBhAe3x7joscCABN6WEBHz8A7hMwBzERCptW7cNHjJgAZwCCVUb35w9QgArNgSbPgA8Ab1ZQoAbQDSEEFCRUoAAodFFJuPgEASgBdAC4ob18IAA9gVVELENQAfigqBABbcghBeMSoFLTjC1MBKFzyHj4Iaih4qggANxKAblYAXwA%20DQBjHio9VB5yACsIEeB4rMNjWvMhFzdcAgh4gEYAGlcoEVF4gDN7PQgj-qA)

Comment: don't do that. this looks very unreadable, especially if you add more than 2 mappings in the future.

Comment: @szaman Agree. I just want to let OP know about this alternative.

Comment: This is great if your types are the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript syntax for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) doesn't allow multiple mappings. There are two ways you can achieve what you want:

1. You can use a type union, like the one in your question.
2. You can also use `Record<Fruit, number> & Record<Color, boolean>`.

As mentioned in the other answer, note that this will make all properties required, so wrap it all in `Partial` if that's not what you want.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8sAjbAO2u2LM0mzkwFgAoUSKAYQHt8fOOixwIAE3pYQEfIIDuUzAHMxEKm3Ycu0AB7xkwAM4BBKuP6C4RkQG8OUKAG0A1hBBQkVWIhQBdAC4oKgQAW3IIOABuB2c3Dy9eASFAqHI+AQhqKKgAelyocT4IIyoAclR5IRcOAF8ObXBoEzkDFFNzSyEbDAAlCABjIXEAHjbgABpgsIi4AD4oADIofqG4Ua64KfTM6jmYziafQw6LZOsRAAVmYCRsfBHV4bHfSenwyIXlp-WRze2MoQ9vsGuxCKhsEFxqdNj0oPZ2I5HGJxEFgIgIHUokA)

Also note that types should start with a capital letter. This is a TS convention that helps with syntax highlighting.

Comment: The Record variant looks neat!